# Hibernate on Multiple Tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here is a diagram of my database 
[image]
I want to get the information from my `tables` and `dataweb`, `gmail` and `blogger`.I am a newbie, I can choose to be the easiest to execute the query, I have read some of the documents and related questions.

I use the following query:

```
 String sql = "SELECT parseUrl,w.url,w.status,title,content,label,labelTXT,desctiption,b.user,accessToken,clientID,clientSecret,p12FileLocation,b.lastModifiedTime\n"
                + " FROM MdDataweb w,MdParse p,MdParseBlogger pb,MdBlogger b,MdGmail g \n"
                + " INNER JOIN w.url=p.url\n"
                + " INNER JOIN p.url =pb.url\n"
                + " INNER JOIN pb.blog=b.blog\n"
                + " INNER JOIN b.user=g.user";
        return currentSession.createQuery(sql).list();
```

But when I play it is always an error message, please help me

```
thg 12 02, 2015 2:31:22 CH org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 3:24: unexpected token: =
thg 12 02, 2015 2:31:22 CH org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 3:24: unexpected token: =
line 3:24: unexpected token: =
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1687)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1371)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1077)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:723)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.showDataweb(DBTable.java:73)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.main(DBTable.java:79)

thg 12 02, 2015 2:31:22 CH org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 4:26: unexpected token: =
thg 12 02, 2015 2:31:22 CH org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 4:26: unexpected token: =
line 4:26: unexpected token: =
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1687)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1371)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1077)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:723)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.showDataweb(DBTable.java:73)
    at dbUtility.DBTable.main(DBTable.java:79)
```

Comment: please read a tutorial about hibernate. this query is completly wrong

Comment: And if you map your entities right, you will not have to do joins by yourself like you do now.

Comment: Your sql is not a valid hibernate query. Show your entities.

Comment: Thank all,@Antoniossss   please give me a specific path, there is so much material I do not know where to start

Answer (score 1):

The below approach will execute your query.But if you write your entities perfectly you can write simplified HQL queries.

```
String sql = "SELECT parseUrl,w.url,w.status,title,content,label,labelTXT,desctiption,b.user,accessToken,clientID,clientSecret,p12FileLocation,b.lastModifiedTime\n"
            + " FROM MdDataweb w,MdParse p,MdParseBlogger pb,MdBlogger b,MdGmail g"
            + " INNER JOIN w.url=p.url"
            + " INNER JOIN p.url =pb.url"
            + " INNER JOIN pb.blog=b.blog"
            + " INNER JOIN b.user=g.user";

SQLQuery sqlQuery = (SQLQuery)  currentSession.createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YourDTO.class));
sqlQuery.addScalar("parseUrl", StringType.INSTANCE);
sqlQuery.addScalar("url", DoubleType.INSTANCE);
// like this add all your columns which are in select 
// YourDTO.class should have all these properties and its setter and getters
return sqlQuery.list();
```